# How to access struct pointer in struct?

Tags: c

I not entirely sure how to phrase this, but can't figure out how to access a struct pointer within another struct. How would I print the values in struct `first_name *hello`, given the structs below. I can't figure out the syntax.

```
struct first_name
{
    char *word
    int number
};

struct last_name{

    struct first_name *hello

    int num2

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the semicolons in the structures:

Correct would be

```
struct first_name
{
    char *word;
    int number;
};

struct last_name{
    struct first_name *hello;
    int num2;
};
```

You can access the members like any other members of the structure.

```
struct first_name fn = { .word = "Hello", .number = 23 };

printf("word: %s, number = %d\n", fn.word, fn.number);


struct last_name ln = { .hello = &fn, .num2 = 11 };

printf("name: %s, number: %d, num2: %d\n", ln.hello->word, ln.hello->number, ln.num2);
```

The output would be:

```
word: Hello, number = 23
name: Hello , number: 23, num2: 11
```